# Can typeid() be used to pass a function?

Tags: c++

I tried this and got the output as:
void

Please explain the following Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std ;

void foo()
{    }

int main(void)
{
   printf("%s", 
     typeid(foo()).name());// Please notice this line, is it same as typeid( ).name() ?
   return 0;
}
```

AFAIK:
The typeid operator allows the type of an object to be determined at run time.

So, does this sample code tell us that **a function that returns void is of **type** void**.
I mean a function is a method and has no type. Correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`typeid` does not work with *objects*. It works with *expressions*.

`typeid` returns the type of the expression you supply to it as an argument. The expression can refer to an object, or to something that is not an object. You supplied expression `foo()` as an argument. This expression has type `void`. So, you got a result that refers to type `void`. `void`, BTW, is not an object type.

Function do have types. If you want to apply `typeid` to the function itself, the syntax would be `typeid(foo)`. The function-to-pointer conversion is not applied to the argument of `typeid`, which means that you should get a result that refers to function type itself. Meanwhile, `typeid(&foo)` will give you a function pointer type id, which is different from `typeid(foo)`.

Comment: +1 just to add a little clarity to an already-correct response, the expression `typeid(foo())` first calls the function `foo()` and then does `typeid` on `foo()`'s return value, which is `void`

Comment: @John Dibling: This is not entirely accurate. The function is *not* called. `typeid` only evaluates its expression when it has polymorphic class type. In all other cases (including this one) it is similar to `sizeof`, meaning that the argument expression is *not* evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

That is telling you the type of the function's return.

To get the type of the function itself, you want:

```
typeid(foo)       // note the lack of ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong on both counts.

1) The sample code tells you that the type of the result of calling foo() is void.

2) Functions are also types.

Comment: Functions are definitely not types, though they do *have* a type. :)

Comment: @avakar - it's a rather pedantic issue but based on the language of the standard I'd have to disagree.  3.9.2/1 "Compound types can be constructed in the following ways: ... --/functions/..." and 8.3.5/1 "...a type of this form is a /function type/". (slants meant to represent italic type in the text)